# Take the inverse of a where clause to extract the difference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My original query returns 7975 rows.  Adding a where clause, I receive 7917 rows.  I want to `SELECT` the 58 row difference.  In an effort to do so, I wrote what I believe to be the inverse where clause.  Unfortunetly, I only see 41 rows, instead of the expected 58.

Both TableName.Column and TableName.Column2 are nullable.

Original Where

```
where ((TableName.Column in ('1', '2', '3))
or (TableName.Column2 in ('1', '2', '3))
```

My attempt at an inverse

```
where ((TableName.Column not in ('1', '2', '3))
and (TableName.Column2 not in ('1', '2', '3))
```

Comment: What happens when you change `(TableName.Column2 not in ('1', '2', '3)) ` to `(COALESCE(TableName.Column2, '0') not in ('1', '2', '3))`?

Comment: Where would you like the null rows to feature (guessing in the second case)? If so just add a `Or TableName.Column2 Is Null`. Alternatively change your query so that you select all rows where the row unique id isn't selected by the original where.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - still 41 results.

Comment: Are `column` and `column2` nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with NULLs.  The real inverse is either:

```
where (coalesce(TableName.Column, '') not in ('1', '2', '3))
```

or:

```
where tableName is NULL or (TableName.Column not in ('1', '2', '3))
```

With both columns, this would be:

```
where (coalesce(TableName.Column, '') not in ('1', '2', '3)) and
      (coalesce(TableName.Column2, '') not in ('1', '2', '3)
```

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey . . . yes, that is the right thing to do.  The SQL query has the second clause in a different color.  It looked commented out to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TableName 
EXCEPT 
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TableName 
WHERE 
    ((TableName.Column IN ('1', '2', '3))
    OR (TableName.Column2 IN ('1', '2', '3))
```

By the way I'd suspect NULL values are throwing off your results. Null values are not `IN` and they are also not `NOT IN` a particular set.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, SQL's 3-way logic mandates that `null` fails all tests save for an explicit test for nullity.

If `x` is null then the test `x = 3` fails as does the text `x != 3`. Further the test `x = null` fails (this is not an explicit test for nullity). The only test that succeeds or fails "properly" for nulls is the test `x is [not] null`.

The problem with SQL Server is that its default behaviour WRT `null` doesn't work that way.

However, if you write your SQL queries to properly check for null/non-null, the query will work properly regardless of database bahaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you have a `'` and a `)` missing on both your wheres. I suppose it is a typo.

So your original query is:

```
where ((X) or (Y))
```

and you changed to

```
where ((!X) and (!Y))
```

which is not the same thing. On the first example, only one of the conditions need to be true to evaluate the query, so a row with 1 on the Column would be returned. On the second, both need to be true so it will only return rows that dont have 1, 2 or 3 on column 1 AND on column 2

what exactly do you need to return?